# How to turn a script into a daemon? So that upon a random script failure it is restarted by the kernel?

Tags: linux, service, daemon, streaming

I have a script which streams important logs from another system.

Unfortunately the machines are separated by a large distance which means that the connection between them can be poor.

How to deal with a script which streams data, but has a tendency to stop? Is there an easy way to turn a script into a daemon so that upon an exit, the kernel restarts the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on a systemd OS? Writing a unit file is pretty straightforward.

http://patrakov.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 16.04LTS which uses systemd. Thank you